# iOSのwebViewでjavascriptを呼び出し、返り値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, ios

iOSのUIWebViewで、ロードしたページ内のjavascriptを呼び出し戻り値をiOS側に格納したいです。
どのような方法があるでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webViewにロードしたhtmlが例えば次のようになっていた場合、

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function test(value){
        return JSON.stringify({result : value * 2});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

次のように[stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)を呼び出すことで、返り値を取得できます。

```
NSString *function = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"test(%i)", 1];
NSString *jsonString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
```

なお、`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`の戻り値はNSStringなので、シンプルなデータであればJSONで受け渡しする必要はないです。

また、Objective-C -> JSは以上のように簡潔にできますが、JS -> Objective-Cについては、`UIWebView`には、C#の`WebBrowser`にある`ObjectForScripting`のような実装がないので簡潔には書けません（OSXであれば、[windowScriptObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/windowScriptObject)というのが使えるようです）。C#の`WebBrowser`では、例えば、

```
window.external.CSharpMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

のように書けます。

ここでのトピックから外れますので詳細については割愛しますが、
[JavaScriptからObjective-Cにフック](http://qiita.com/ozw_sei/items/62d9cd1938cf6ea012bd#2-2)や[Calling Objective-C code from UIWebView](http://pablin.org/2013/08/31/interfacing-with-a-uiwebview-from-a-uiviewcontroller/)などを参考にして下さい。